# Denying direct access to directory and its contents with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Say as an example i have a folder full of .txt files that i don't want external or direct access to (such as via browser address bar). I know i can use the:

```
deny from all
```

htaccess method, but my question is this.. If the above htaccess denies all direct access to said files unless including them in php, does that mean that someone else could do the same remotely? ie. calling the file in their php?

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but i couldn't find anywhere that answered it.

Also, are there any better methods than the above one? Basically i want to be able to call the file in php, but never be able to access it any other way.

**edit*** This should include all sub-directories too.

**edit 2** example file structure

```
/MainDir
  .htaccess
  /SubDirA
    .file1
    .file2
    .file3
  /SubDirB
    .file1
    .file2
    .file3
  /SubDirC
    .file1
    .file2
    .file3
```

Thanks.

Comment: Someone else where? They would only be able to access those files if their PHP code was running on your server.

Comment: You can also store the directory outside your web root. PHP should be able to include files from anywhere in your file system, as long as the permissions are set properly.

Comment: I may have written it incorrectly, what i meant was.. If a txt file on my server had deny from all on it, would someone on another server be able to call it from php like i could from mine if they knew the full url or would that still return as an error page too?

Comment: No, someone on another server could _try_ to include it with PHP if they knew the full URL, but their PHP script would request it via HTTP, just like you would if you tried to access it with a browser, and if it was in a directory with a `deny from all` .htaccess, your Apache server would not allow them to access it.

Comment: That's what i thought, but i wanted to make sure before using it. Thank you for the confirmation :)

Comment: Can i make this work for all subdirectory files or do all subdirectories also require a htaccess file?

Comment: rewrite rules should inherit to subdirectories. But really, if you want to be completely certain that Apache will never serve those files directly, I'd advise storing them outside the web root.

Comment: Thanks. My current setup doesn't allow me to store outside of root which is why i am doing this method.

Comment: Problem i have is the subdirectories are dynamically named/created, so i need some kind of wildcard 403 rewrite rule, but nothing i've tried works, it always still lets me download the contents on the subdirectory, only the folder itself goes 403.

Comment: That's strange. Can you edit the question to try to show your directory structure, where the dynamic subdirectories are created, and where your .htaccess is in relation?

Comment: Update: i fixed it, just had a typo in my rewrite. I really shoudlnt work this late :)